# Does anyone using Repl.it? Not working another python file

Tags: python, replit

As you know, there is Main.py and we can make a multiple files
even yesterday, I made a new file(not Main.py) named so.py and it works well when I press run button
but today I try to run like that there is nothing on the result screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it was working yesterday and not today, then it might be a connection issue when you were trying to run the code this time around. That sometimes happens to me as well, but a refresh or two should work.

You've probably done that already so try copying your code to a new repl and try again.

Check for missing code you might have deleted, like an ***import*** statement in `main.py` which would explain why code isn't showing up. Assuming you're calling code from a different file or package.

Kindly note that your question isn't very clear so more details pertaining to your question would be appreciated.

---

Okay, one thing to clarify is that repl always runs **main.py** so you'll have to enter the following to have access to functions from the other files.

```py
import indeed
import so
```

If you're expecting to run so.py by itself on repl I don't think it's going to work.
Now that you have them imported you can use any function in so.py by using the **.** notation.
e.g:

```py
so.print_hello()
```

Or you could also import a specific function into main.py using this method

```py
from so import function_name, function2_name, etc...
```

To make it as clear as possible here is example code if I had done it.

In so.py

```py
def print_hello():
   print('Hello, World!')
```

In main.py

```py
import so


so.print_hello()
```

Output will be

> Hello, World!

Comment: Hi Frank. Eng isn't my first language so I can't explain all of my wonders. I'm sorry about that. actually I just thought about that is just a connection issue. interestingly, there are 3 files such as main.py, indeed.py and so(stackoverflow).py I want to run in so.py which one is problem or not. i think in def func, it didn't work any print()

Comment: Sorry I just noticed what you wrote int the comment. I've edited my answer accordingly.